# Storing a file inside a temporary buffer before uploading to S3 bucket. Python Flask

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, buffer

I have an endpoint that gets a parameter "address".
Using this parameter I am generating an image and saving it on the OS, uploading it to an s3 - bucket and serve it using the s3-bucket.

I feel like the image generation on the OS step is redundant as I do not even serve the image from the OS but It is needed because Amazon s3 askes for the image file to upload.

Is there a way to pass it? Maybe storing the image in some kind of buffer?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you uploading to s3? If you're using boto3, it will support file paths or file-like objects. See [S3.Client.upload_fileobj](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj) There is also the [`flask-s3`](https://github.com/e-dard/flask-s3) extension, which may be of interest to you.

Comment: Please add some code and clarify the question,  otherwise it would be very hard to help.

Comment: I am using boto3. I am uploading images. Are file like objects lighter and will be faster to upload? Regarding asking for code. It is not relevant really, I generate an image, it is being saved in my static folder, I upload it to s3 using boto3 and I serve that image from that s3 bucket.

Comment: It would potentially avoid the overhead of writing the data to disk and reading it a second time to upload to s3. It may also spare you the need to cleanup the local filesystem. To make this question more answerable, it may help to share the relevant code.

Comment: Well actually when I saw "file-like object" I've searched it and eventually BytesIO did the trick. It actually made things faster (reduced the unnecessary overhead you have mentioned) Thanks all.